# What is difference b/w Functional and Transitive dependency in database

Tags: sql, database

Yesterday i was reading Normalization and found that
  A relation is in 2NF if it is in 1NF and doesn't contain partial and functional dependency.
A relation is in third normal form, if it is in 2NF and doesn't contain any Transitive dependency.
Now my question is that what is difference b/w functional and Transitive dependency

Comment: What did you try?  Have you googled something?

Answer (score 9):

**Transitive dependency** is expressing the dependency of A on C when A depends on B and B depends on C.

**A functional dependency** is an association between two attributes of the same relational database table. One of the attributes is called the determinant and the other attribute is called the determined. For each value of the determinant there is associated one and only one value of the determined.

If A is the determinant and B is the determined then we say that A functionally determines B and graphically represent this as A -> B. The symbols A à B· can also be expressed as B is functionally determined by A.

Answer (score 2):

**Functional Dependency**

Functional dependency can be defined as relationship that exits between attributes in relation. Functional dependencies are used to create relation in Boyce Codd Normal Form abbreviated as BCNF. If C and D are the attributes of relation R and attribute C functionally determines attributes D then the functional dependency between both attribute can be expressed as C->D. i.e C->D means whenever two tuple in relation R agree with on all the attributes of X, they must also agree on all the attributes of Y.

i.e C->D means whenever two tuple in R agree

Example : Below the person schema

person(national_id, name, address);

Here national_id functionally determines the person_name. So functional dependency is national_id -> name;

**Transitive Dependency**

Transitive dependency is one kind of functional dependency in which a non prime attribute is determined by another non prime attribute. Suppose C and D are the non prime attributes and A is the prime attribute of relation R .

If A functional determines C and C functionally determines D

A->C

C->D

Then the transitive functional dependency between both attribute can be expressed as

A->D

Example : Below the student schema in which PostCode and City are non prime attribute.

student(#Id, Name, Age, PostCode, City)

Here , Id functionally determines PostCode and PostCode functionally determines the City attribute. So transitive functional dependency is

Id->City

Answer (score 1):

You can refer wiki:

[Functional dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency)

> In relational database theory, a functional dependency is a constraint
>   between two sets of attributes in a relation from a database.

[Transitive dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency)

> In Database Management System, a transitive dependency is a functional
>   dependency which holds by virtue of transitivity. A transitive
>   dependency can occur only in a relation that has three or more
>   attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> A functional dependency *X->Y* in a relation schema *R* is a transitive
>   dependency if there exists a set of attributes *Z* in *R* that is neither
>   a candidate key nor a subset of any key of *R*, and both *X->Z* and *Z->Y* hold.

Taken from: Fundamentals of Database Systems 6th edition - Elmasri et al;